# Double click on the zip file has to self-extract the file in the specified path

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip

I have filename.zip file and if double click the file it has to extract the file in the desired location("c:\user\username"). I have tried using the batch file but didnt give me the required result.

```
@echo on
@set nested=%nested%Z
set _dest=c:\user\username
if NOT EXIST %_dest% md %_dest%
```

So if i double click on zip file it has to execute batch file to place file in the destination folder path.How can i do that?

Comment: Sorry, its not very clear. Are you wanting to change the batch files working dir, or extract a zip file to a custom location?

Comment: @09stephenb Extract a zip file to a custom location when we double click on the folder. It means extract the file to dest folder.

Comment: So you want a batch file to detect when you double click on a folder and then automatically extract?

Comment: Extracting the zip would be quite easy, but detecting that a zip file was opened would be harder. I think its possible, by detecting the the process. But i'm not sure. I would recommend using C++, or auto-it, because they will be better at detecting that the zip file was opened.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you simply want to extract a `.zip` archive to a *previously defined* directory `c:\user\username`, when the user clicks that `.zip` archive.

No, this is not possible.

A `.zip` file has no default extraction destination. Nor has is a way to execute scripts upon extraction. It is just a container for compressed data. When you click it, *your OS* runs *a program* configured to handle `.zip` files, allowing you to view the contents, extract the contents, etc - but what and how exactly, is up to the user that clicked the file.

What you effectively want to have is an *installer*. Here are some pointers for options to do that:

- [Microsoft IExpress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress)
- [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)
- [Quasi-installer using 7-zip self-extracting archive](https://superuser.com/questions/42788/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-file-after-extraction-from-a-7-zip-self-extracting-a)

Comment: It could be possible if the batch file changed the default program to open a zip to its self. So when the zip file is open it automatically executes the batch file.

Comment: Fair enough. But then you would be clicking a `.bat` file and then a `.zip` file, which is not what was asked.

Comment: If the default program was changed to the bat file, then instead of windows explorer opening the zip file, the bat file would be automatically executed instead. Read my last comment, "automatically executes the batch file".

Comment: "...if the batch file changed the default program..." sounds like you meant to execute that batch file first. Anyhow: of course you can reconfigure a system to handle `.zip` files anyway you like. But if it's just about a single system, you might as well extract the archive to the intended location in the first place, right?

Comment: Right, i was meaning the bat file would need to be run once on the PC, but after that it would already be set as the default program.